# How to convert mp3 to wav with JMF and mp3plugin.jar?

Tags: java, mp3, wav, jmf, file-conversion

I have to convert an mp3 data into wav  in java.I am using JMF with mp3plugin.jar ,I am able to play the mp3 with it,seems there is a way to convert it into wav along with channel,bitwidth and fps information which I need to process further,but don't know how to do it.Any help is admired

Comment: Hey I am also figuring out this, right now.. :)

Comment: 1) [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (of your closest attempt). 3) Although the `mp3plugin.jar` is necessary for decoding MP3, the rest of the JMF is not needed for this task.  Use Java Sound instead.